# Fragment Nullpointer Exception on Interface Callback

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make my first Android app and I'm stuck with the following problem:

I implemented an interface in my host activity, which I have created. The problem is that I get a `NullPointerException` when I call the method in my fragment.

**Interface**

```
public interface GameInterface {
    public void gameOver();
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
...
    GameInterface gameInterface;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Button trueButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_true);
        trueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
        gameInterface.gameOver();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GameInterface {
...
    private void showStartFragment() {
        StartFragment startFragment = new StartFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, startFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }  

    @Override
    public void gameOver() {
        showStartFragment();
    }
}
```

I get the `NullPointerException` in the fragment on the line where I call `gameInterface.gameOver();`.

Comment: Declare the interface in the `Fragment` and use `implements GameFragment.GameInterface` for the `Activity` instead of just `implements GameInterface`. Then follow the advice from the answer by user2713030 and set your `gameInterface` in your `Fragment` in the `onAttach` method of the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable was not initialized. Add that in `onActivityCreated`

```
gameInterface = (GameInterface) getActivity();
```

Assuming `GameFragment` is created in `MainActivity`

Edit (thanks @Squonk):

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    gameInterface = (GameInterface) activity
}
```

Comment: It's usual to do that in `onAttach(...)`.